# Cloud Functions for Firebase monitor node leaf if deleted check if parent exists

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am monitoring for changes in node leaf jobs/{jobid}/proposals. Whenever I remove the proposals the function gets executed and reinsert proposals (this is the expected behavior).
The problem is When I remove its parent {job}, proposals gets reinserted in a new object with same parent ID. Is there a way to do a check if the parent exists? If so, reinsert proposal otherwise not.

```
exports.RecountProposals = functions.database.ref("/jobs/{jobid}/proposals").onWrite(event => {
    const jobid = event.params.jobid;
    if (!event.data.exists() && event.data.ref.parent.exists()) {
        const propRef = admin.database().ref(`proposals/${jobid}`);
        const counterRef = event.data.ref;
        const collectionRef = counterRef.parent.child('proposals');
        // Return the promise from counterRef.set() so our function
        // waits for this async event to complete before it exits.
        return propRef.once('value')
            .then(messagesData => collectionRef.set(messagesData.numChildren()));
    }
});
```

I am checking if parent exists but it is showing an error:

> event.data.ref.parent.exists()

TypeError: event.data.ref.parent.exists is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

event.data.ref.parent is a [Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference) type object.  As you can see from the linked doc, there is no exists() method on Reference.  In Realtime Database, if you want to know if there is any data at a node, simply fetch the snapshot there and call val() on it to check to see if it's null.  Reference objects are just paths, they don't contain any knowledge of data.

To put it another way, there is no such concept as a node that "exists" but contains no data, like an empty folder in a filesystem. For any given path that you can construct, the snapshot of the data there is either available (non-null) or not (null).

Comment: Thanks, if a node leaf is being monitored/observed by a function and the parent is deleted. Should the function that observe the node trigger?

Comment: Yes, a function will trigger if *anything* under its matched path changes.  New nodes, changed values, and deleted nodes all trigger.  It's not so much about the parent as the view from the path you give.